# Decoding dig output: +norecurse @nameserver MX to domain

Tags: dig

From the output I can understand there was no errors, yet there aren't any answers section to the query. Just to be sure the right question was even asked:
"Dig +norecurse @s.nic.dk MX www.dtu.dk"
parsing this to:
"without recursion, query dtu mail exchange servers through the nameserver s.nic.dk"

Is the query not supposed to return nameservers of dtu MX?

[image: Dig output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't supposed to, because you are asking the authoritative name server of the TLD (`s.nic.dk`) for the answer. It does not have this answer, but gives you the details of the name servers that do: that is why you receive the authority section (and additional section).

However, even if you do query the authoritative name servers (for example: `@dns1.dtu.dk`) there is no MX record for the domain name `www.dtu.dk`, but rather for `dtu.dk`. Which means your query should be: `dig @dns1.dtu.dk MX dtu.dk`.

For note, the addition of `+norecurse` shouldn't make a difference when you're querying an authoritative name server directly.